# Overlay a Full screen Transparent layer in Android 4.4(KitKat)

Tags: android, view, android-relativelayout, layoutparams, android-windowmanager

I want to overlay a transparent view on the entire screen including the bottom most Navigation Bar in Android 4.4.

I am able to do so in Android 4.3 by defining the window Manager LayoutParams as TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY, but when I use the same definition the layout is now pushed behind the navigation bar. could you please let me know if it due to the recent updates in KitKat? or If any one have a solution please share with me.

regards

Comment: Same issue here, in Android 5.1 Lollipop. Any news on how to overlay the navigation bar?